# TSA requirements regarding ID

Tags: transit

If the name on my boarding pass lists Debbie and my Drivers License lists Debra, will this be a problem?

Comment: @pnuts Bother. I opened this question just to give that answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

According to the TSA's web site:

> **If the name printed on my boarding pass is different than what appears on my government ID, will I be turned away at security and
>   unable to fly?**
>
> Boarding passes may not always display the exact name you provided
>   when booking your travel. The name you provide is used to perform
>   watch list matching before a boarding pass is issued, so small
>   differences should not impact your travel.

Reference: [here](http://www.tsa.gov/content/frequently-asked-questions-secure-flight)